# discord.py remove user (json)

Tags: discord.py

I wish a user has the option to create his account by saving his ID/Removing it from the Json File.
How can I do?

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True, aliases=["Delete", "DELETE", "unregister", "UnRegister", "Unregister", "UNREGISTER", "elimina", "Elimina", "ELIMINA"])
async def delete(ctx):
    id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    lmii = get_emoji(ctx.guild, "VittorianoPuntaFerro")
    embed = discord.Embed(
        color=0x003399
    )
    if id not in amounts:
        #???
        embed.set_author(name="Hai rimosso il tuo account!")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10)
        _save()
    else:
        embed.set_author(name="Hai già registrato un account!")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the ID in the JSON and Even remove it. However, I think you are fully new to this. Json dictionary is the same as the python dictionary but the difference is we store that in a file whereas this is stored in the memory.
Follow this:

**We create the .json empty file. You can rename it anything and save it into the directory where your script is saved.

Open the Json file and edit it, enter {} and save it.**

```
#We import the json module in the python.
import json

async def delete(ctx):
    #OPEN THE JSON FILE 
    with open('your_file_name.json','r') as f:
        #Here we load the dictionary into Amounts Variable, It can be anything
        amounts = json.load(f)
    
    
    id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    lmii = get_emoji(ctx.guild, "VittorianoPuntaFerro")
    embed = discord.Embed(
        color=0x003399
    )
    if id not in amounts:
        
        #TO SAVE THE ID IN THE DICTIONARY 
        amounts[id] = {}

        #To remove the ID From the Dictionary, You can use this.
        #amounts.pop(id)
        
        embed.set_author(name="Hai rimosso il tuo account!")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10)

        #OPEN THE JSON FILE AGAIN FOR WRITING THE DATA
        with open('your_file_name.json','w') as f:
            #SAVE THE CONTENT
            json.dump(amounts,f,indent= 3)

    else:
        embed.set_author(name="Hai già registrato un account!")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10)
```

This is the basic thing about how you can open the JSON file and write the data, Rest all the details are based on the python dictionary. You can explore yourself and learn new ways of implementing your structures.